# Buttons in layout are crammed to left side of screen

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have two buttons (**Next** and **Cancel**) in my layout that are crammed to the left side of the screen and it won't allow me to adjust them past the centre. I tried playing around with the attributes of the buttons to fix it, I even considered placing these buttons in a linear layout in order to organize them with no luck.

I've attached my .xml file, I would really appreciate it if someone can point out where I'm going wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:text="Email"
    android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mobileNum"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="Mobile"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailAddress"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mobileNum"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_above="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/password">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rider"
        android:id="@+id/riderRadioButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/driverRadioButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/driverRadioButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/driverRadioButton"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Driver"
        android:id="@+id/driverRadioButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Your email and number are used to send you ride confirmations"
    android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="13dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/messageTextView">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try making your parent layout linear with a vertical orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `android:gravity` attribute of parent layout to center it's content. Something like:

**EDIT**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:text="Email"
    android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/mobileNum"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="Mobile"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailAddress"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mobileNum"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

 <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/riderRadioButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/riderRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rider"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/driverRadioButton"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/driverRadioButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/driverRadioButton"
            android:checked="false"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/driverRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Driver"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:checked="false"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

 </RadioGroup>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Your email and number are used to send you ride confirmations"
    android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="13dp"/>

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"/>
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That didn't fix it for me. Thanks though! @gar_r

Comment: What exactly does not work? (I've edited original example - proposed solution is now part of your parent layout)

Answer (score 0):

At the time, I didn't have experience with xml files. However, I have been able to fix it now. I removed the LinearLayout which contained the buttons, and played around with some attributes to get it to work.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="daniaghazal.com.hitchhikr.SignUpPage">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mobileNum"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:hint="Mobile"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailAddress"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mobileNum"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/riderRadioButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/riderRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rider"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/driverRadioButton"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/driverRadioButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/driverRadioButton"
            android:checked="false"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/driverRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Driver"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:checked="false"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Your email and number are used to send you ride confirmations"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="13dp"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nextButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```